# SQL Dependent Percentage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sample data

[image]

Excepted output

[image]

Math Operation

- Sum all Period time for each `EmpName` as `Total Employee Time`
- Sum Similar Tasks For `EmpName`, divide it by `Total Employee Time` and multiply by 100%

please help me

I am using SQL Server Management 2008 and here is my try:

```
select EmpName,Task,Period_Time, 
sum(Period_Time)/(select sum(Period_Time) as total from dbo.TableName) 
as percentage 
from  dbo.TableName 
group by EmpName,Task,Period_Time 
order by EmpName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your approach. The two issues with it that I can see are:

1. **The subquery is not correlated with the outer query.** Your subquery needs to have a `WHERE` clause to limit the rows only to those where `EmpName` is the same as the outer query's `EmpName`.

   In order to be able to reference the outer query's columns, you need to assign a different alias to either instance of `dbo.TableName`. It would probably be best to assign one to each – something like this:

   ```
   SELECT
     ...
     (SELECT ... FROM dbo.TableName AS b WHERE b.EmpName = a.EmpName)
   FROM
     dbo.TableName AS a
   ...
   ```
2. **The main query does not need to group by `Period_Time`**, because it is aggregating that value.

   Just remove the `Period_Time` column from both the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`.

So, this is how your query could look like after addressing both issues:

```
SELECT
  EmpName,
  Task,
  Percentage  = SUM(Period_Time) * 100.0
              / (
                  SELECT
                    SUM(b.Period_Time)
                  FROM
                    dbo.TableName AS b
                  WHERE
                    b.EmpName = a.EmpName
                )
FROM
  dbo.TableName AS a
GROUP BY
  EmpName,
  Task
ORDER BY
  EmpName
;
```

However, you could do better than using a correlated subquery here. Since SQL Server 2005, Transact-SQL has started supporting [*window*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) aggregate functions. They allow you to obtain aggregate results alongside detail results and use both in various calculations – exactly what you need for your problem.

Basically, the syntax would go like this:

```
SELECT
  SomeKey,
  DetailData,
  TotalData = SUM(DetailData) OVER (PARTITION BY SomeKey),
  -- or you can get percentage directly, like this:
  -- Percentage = DetailData * 100.0 / SUM(DetailData) OVER (PARTITION BY SomeKey)
FROM
  dbo.SomeTable
;
```

There is only one issue: you cannot calculate the total `Period_Time` like this:

```
SUM(Period_Time) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpName)
```

because in your case `Period_Time` would be an invalid reference: that column is not in GROUP BY and may not be referenced without being enclosed in a (non-window) aggregate function. Your main query already aggregates it using SUM – that is how it can be used in `SUM ... OVER` as well:

```
SUM(SUM(Period_Time)) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpName)
```

For reference, [here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5334a0/1) of a complete query that calculates percentage using window aggregation instead of a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
  EmpName,
  Task,
  Percentage  = SUM(Period_Time) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(Period_Time)) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpName)
FROM
  dbo.TableName
GROUP BY
  EmpName,
  Task
ORDER BY
  EmpName
;
```

Comment: many thanks, it's working and I got it, thanks again for extra information, it's being useful and helpful